# Visual Studios 2012 - Large C# solution - Analysis into slow builds?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build

I'm experiencing a sudden increase in build time for a large solution I work on that is comprised mainly of C# based libraries. The solution use to build in about as min. Now it's gotten to 5-7 mins. Looking at the change logs I don't see anything that would effect build times this much.

Searching about this on my own, I find the internet has an abundance of tips to improve build times but that doesn't sit right with me. Sounds more like a bandaid fix for the problem at hand.

I would like to know what exactly it's doing and what steps in the build process is taking the longest and then take steps to remedy what it's hung up on.

Is there anything within VS that can give me a more verbose build output? Any tips on what could be a common hang up with the build process?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Another developer had added build events to re-order resx files. After removing it, the first build was still slow but subsequent builds after that took 11 seconds! Lesson learned.

Comment: I hope the real lesson you learned here was that you won't get an answer unless you can provide information.  There is no way anyone here could have known this situation, so your likelihood of getting an answer was 0.

Comment: Uhh yeah ok dude. My build was slow and I simply asked if there was a tool or built in solution that can provide more output info when i build so I can pinpoint what os slow. What more do people need?